# Unbind event on Dynatree

Tags: javascript, dynatree

I need to unbind/off the event `onSelect` in my Dynatree, How can I do this?
if this is my treeview object:

```
$("#MenuTree").dynatree("getTree")
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#MenuTree").dynatree("getTree").options.onSelect = null`

This will unbind the function that you call when you select a Node.

Comment: Ok I'll try it, and if I need to put it back?

Comment: I mean, activate it again?

Comment: You should keep a variable with the function and put it there if you want to activate again..